# Drupal page won't stay https, redirection loop

Tags: drupal, ssl, https

On a Drupal 6 site we can't figure out why pages, other than the home page, refuse to be accessed in https.  Accessing any page on the site, except the home page, immediately redirects back to itself at http.

- Apache is correctly setup with a valid SSL certificate.
- I'm certain its not the .htaccess file. There's no rewrite rules regarding https or port 443.
- I added $conf['https'] = TRUE; to the settings.php
- I installed the Secure Page module and configured it to secure the page we want, but it causes a redirection loop ending in a browser error.
- No other modules that I can see relate to http vs. https
- I can't find any admin settings regarding the base URL that would force this behavior.

I have a lot of experience with server admin, LAMP software, and a little with Drupal, but this one has me stumped.  Any hints or suggestions would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if base url in settings.php is set to the http address.  This can cause this behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not set.  Its still commented out with default settings.  Just to be sure it wasn't somewhere else I grep'd the code for base_url and the domain, but didn't come up with anything.